# Quick Integration Clarification

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \int_ {-\pi}^{\pi}\ f(x) \ dx  $ is equivalent to integrating $f(x)$ over $-\pi < x < \pi$ (strictly less than) and also $-\pi \le x \le \pi$ (less than or equal). So I just need to reassure myself that the bounds of integration don't change when considering either less than or less than or equal. A quick confirmation will do.

Cheers.

UPDATE:Just applying this to a question to do with fourier series: $\
f(x) = \begin{cases}x+π & -π<x\le 0 \\ π & 0 < x < π\\  \end{cases} $ with 2π periodicity.
Can I proceed to compute:

$a_0= {1\over 2L}[\displaystyle \int \limits_{-π}^{0} \ x+π \ dx + \int \limits_{0}^{π} π\ dx]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With respect to your edit**, Yes, you can compute this particular integral (and evaluate "at" the bounds $I(x) \big|_b^a$, but keep in mind Jon Claus's answer: that what you are ***really*** doing is evaluating the limit of $I(x)$ as $x \to a^-, x\to b^+$, and that's crucial to remember in the case of *improper integrals*.

Answer (score 3):

No, the bounds are not included which is crucial when evaluating improper integrals. For example, if $ f(x) = \sqrt{\left|\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|} $, then the integral converges despite the integrand not being defined at the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is true (assuming a proper riemann integral, otherwise you must take a limit). Think of it in terms of the area under a curve, ie. you want to calculate the area under the curve f(x) where the end points are $-\pi$, and $\pi$. Clearly the end point don't contribute a nonzero amount to the area.

Comment: The Riemann integral is only defined on closed sets.